Surface of a sphere bounded by circles intersecting sphere
first time poster. I have a pet project where I would like to render solar system or star level objects to scale from a person's pov. I would like to generate the mesh geometry to throw into an engine like Unreal since polygonal mesh at that scale would look like garbage without sufficient tessellation. I do not think I can tesellate an earth scale object from a 2m high camera without significant size/performance penalties, so I am thinking of performing a partial tesselation by clipping the sphere of earth against the camera's view frustum. From what I see this essentially is a plane/sphere intersection with circles intersecting the sphere being coplanar with the planes of the view frustum.
So here in my question lie, is there a term for finding the surface on a sphere bounded by this collection of planes intersecting a sphere?
The easier way of doing this is probably ray tracing, but I would like to stick with geometry that unreal or unity can use for now.
Tq

Try to look for spherical cap, section of sphere, spherical triangle, spherical geometry, etc.
